# Linux install4j installer changes/resets target folder permission to default (755) upon uninstall

Tags: install4j

We've discovered that our Linux install4j installer changes/resets target folder permission to default (755) upon uninstall.

More details below.

**Before installation:**

- target main "app" folder does not exist

**During installation:**

- target main "app" folder gets created with 775 Linux permissions

**After un-installation:**

- target main "app" folder gets updated/changed/reset to have 755 Linux permissions (which is the default Linux folder permission ... at least for the default umask 022)

Since we have other files in the main "app" folder (e.g. log files not owned by install4j), it makes sense that this main folder does not get deleted upon uninstall. But what we need is to make sure the Linux permissions set on it during installation stay the same after uninstall. Otherwise, if someone tries to install the instal4j installer again, the required 775 permissions are not getting set properly on the folder (probably because install4j detects that it already exists).

Is there a way to preserve the 775 Linux folder permission upon an uninstall in case the folder is left behind?

Thank you,

Ciprian

**UPDATE on 10-MAR-2021**

Just to wrap up this thread, the conclusion is:

- Linux permissions (directory mode) for the main installation directory (target folder) are not handled consistently between install and uninstall stages:

  - 775 at install time (even though we are explicitly setting it to 774 in the install4j project)

    - this is not fixed in 8.0.11; from the change log, it seems it got fixed in 9.0.0:
      *"Linux/Unix installers: The configured Unix directory mode was not used for the installation directory"*
  - 755 after uninstall while leaving the main installation directory intact due to containing an extra log file (even though we are explicitly setting it to 774 in the install4j project)

    - this was fixed in version 8.0.7; I'm testing with 8.0.11 but we can see the matching change log under 8.0.7:
      *"Linux: The uninstaller could change the mode of directories that were not removed"*

Full install4j changelog under:
https://www.ej-technologies.com/download/install4j/changelog.html

Comment: I don't see this here. Can you run the uninstaller with `-Dinstall4j.log=<path to writable log file>` and see if there is any mention of the mode change in the log file?

Comment: Thanks for the response Ingo.

Comment: I've done that and here is the link with the results: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1XvF7kX_efZuziOsiHekPY8Bd5BDatwxh . Do you see anything suspicious? Could it be we have some hidden action somewhere that changes the permission to the default? Thanks again for looking at this, Ciprian

Comment: Can you send the install4j profile file to support@ej-technologies.com? Then I could check if there are any such scripts in it.

Comment: Sure can, I'll do that today. Thanks.